# When accessing modules

Tags: perl, module, package

I have a question about packages, modules and syntax. When you access a package in the same file I notice you'd use something like....

```
package test;
$testVar="This is a test";

#and to access it using..

package main;
print($test::testVar);
```

or simply...

```
package test;
print($testVar);
```

Yet when I use this syntax for use with a module, sending an argument, I am supposed to ommit the $ from the start of the print function, yet above I don't. I noticed it didn't work otherwise and I don't know why. My materials don't clarify.

```
require module;
print(package::sub("argument"));
```

Why is that?. I'm confused.

Answer (score 5):

The dollar sign here is a sigil that indicates that the named variable is a scalar.

If there is no preceding `package` declaration, the use of `$var_name` contains an implied namespace of `main`, i.e. it is short for `$main::var_name`. In the case of your example, where you have `package main;` first, you need to stipulate that the namespace is `test`, rather than `main`, so `$test::testVar` is required.

For a function call, you do not need to use a sigil. If you did, you would use the ampersand (`&`), but using ampersands when calling functions has fallen out of favour with many programmers.*

As before, `sub_name()` is a shortened version of `main::sub_name()`... in the same way, no sigil is needed to call `package::sub()`.

*References as to the use of `&`:

- [Perl Monks discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=428024)
- [Perl::Critic](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Perl-Critic/Perl/Critic/Policy/Subroutines/ProhibitAmpersandSigils.pm.html) dislikes it, following on from [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735)
- Per [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html), using `&` with a function name allows you to deviate from the **usual** behaviour. This can result in subtle bugs.

Comment: Ampersands are not deprecated in any way, shape or form.  Some people just dislike them and they are often unnecessary, and using & without also using () creates a special kind of sub call that isn't usually intended.  That last bit is sometimes used as an argument against using & in general, but I don't find it compelling.

Comment: @ysth fair comment. I've reworded and added some links to expand on that bit.

Comment: I sort of, understand. I thought you were going to say, in the case of the module, the script isn't in the same main:: symbol table. I am very new to Perl to be honest and it's given me some issues.

Comment: tye's link in that first link is a great summary: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=29139

Comment: The default namespace in `$var_name` is not `main`, but whatever the current package is.  `main` is just the package you start in before a `package` declaration appears.

Comment: @cjm: that's what default means; `main` is the namespace that is defaulted to, in the absence of an explicit setting of namespace by the `package` declaration.

Comment: You may understand that, but your answer implies that `$var_name` _always_ means `$main::var_name`, which isn't true.  People who don't quite understand packages yet may get confused.

Comment: @cjm: Please comment on all of my posts :o) You make some really good points and I've tweaked the answer a little more to try and clarify.